# Visual Studio Code - How To Replace "X" with a list of data? - JSON

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, replace, yaml, find-replace

I have a question I need to code thousands of lines and instead of doing it manually I want to automate my work flow. So let me present you with some screenshots and a text example of what I am trying to achieve.

**File 1** = `"Blueprint": "XXX'",`
File 1 has several lines of that code above.
[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR8e4.png)

I have a list of strings that I want to add each `line` to replace `XXX` value. I don't want my list to be pasted into a single `XXX` line I want to select all the lines containing `XXX` value and replace them with my list of strings. Each line should be placed into the `XXX` value itself.

**Note**: *I understand I can replace all the "XXX" with a single replacement data but how do I replace each "XXX" with it's own unique line/data?*

I attempted to do this using the visual studio code replacement but it only accepts single replacement data rather then using unique replacement line data.

Answer (score 0):

- in your list file go to the start of the file: `Ctrl+Home`
- click on the last line with `Shift+Alt+Click` to place multi cursors
- Press `Home` (start of the line) and then `Shift+End` (select every line)
- Press `Ctrl+C`
- Take note of the number of lines/cursors (lower left status bar)
- in your JSON file, select first: `"Blueprint": "XXX"`
- Press `Ctrl+D` as much as needed to get the same amount of cursors, you can use key repeat.
- Press `ArrowRight`, `ArrowLeft`, `Backspace`, `Backspace`, `Backspace` (this deletes `XXX`)
- Press `Ctrl+V`
- Press `Esc` (sometimes multiple times, depends on what is shown) to get out of Multi Cursor

If you have more than 10000 places you have to do it in batches.